# Impossible to retrieve playlist tracklist Apple Music API

Tags: api, apple-music, apple-musickit

Since 2am UTC today , there's an error message returned when getting an Apple Music tracklist:

```
{"errors":[{"id":"XXXXXX","title":"Missing Parameter","detail":"No mode supplied on the request","status":"400","code":"40003","source":{"parameter":"mode"}}]
```

On this request for example:
/v1/me/library/playlists/XXXXXX/tracks?limit=100

Worked perfectly before but now always return this error, on any playlist tracklist.

What I have to do to make it works again ? What is the "mode" parameter ?
This one was not required before, and it's no also documented in the doc API Apple Music.

Comment: PS: It's good now, it's back, was just Apple who did some modifications, without any informations...

Comment: HI blackarcanis i m looking up for the same i want to retrive all the songs in the playlist and want to play in my app music player can you please let me know if you are able to access it or any reference doc if you have of apple.